# XCode iOS7 Asset Catalog Warning - Only Supporting iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode, asset-catalog

I am supporting iOS8 and greater in my App. However, I cannot get passed this Image Asset warning. What file am I missing? See the below screenshot:

```
an iphone retina (4-inch) launch image for ios 7.0 and later is required
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've suppled images for 4.7 and 5.5-inch devices but you need to have one for 4-inch devices as well (pre-iPhone 6).

You will need to select the checkboxes under "iOS 7 and later" (iPad ones if you're making an iPad app, iPhone one if iPhone app, all if Universal) at the right pane. These are used in both iOS 7 and 8.

Comment: where does that image get stored? I do not see a spot for it

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! A bit that its labeled under iOS7

Comment: Why on Earth should I supply images for iOS 7 if my app minimum deployment target is iOS 8?